# How do we get dict like string column in Presto from multiple columns?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

We have a table

```
|      Label          |      Value1          |     Value 2      |
| ------------------- | -------------------- |------------------|
|    0.99993938       |    1.88473736        |   2.47467484     |
|    4.66993938       |    10.7473736        |   0.37636378     |
```

How do we create a new column with dict like string?

Expected outcome:

```
|                 Value3                          |
|-------------------------------------------------|
|     {0.99993938 : [1.88473736, 2.47467484]}     |
|     {4.66993938 : [10.7473736, 0.37636378]}     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use plain string concatenation here:

```sql
SELECT Value1, Value2, CONCAT('{', Label, ' : [', Value1, ', ', Value2, ']}') AS Value3
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. This method is showing syntax error.

Comment: @sonia _"This method is showing syntax error"_ please specify the error.

Comment: Message: SQL syntax error: extraneous input 'Value2' expecting {',', ')', 'ORDER'}

Comment: @sonia 1) can you please add your code attempt to the question 2) have you tried answer which I have suggested?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [`MAP`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html#map) type:

```sql
select MAP(ARRAY[label], ARRAY[ ARRAY[Value1, Value2] ]) as value3
from table;
```

Optionally you can then cast it to JSON and format: `json_format(cast(value3 as JSON))`